# Как вывести многомерный массив с динамическими данными?

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

есть такой цикл

```
$tabs[] = array('name'=>$Rusname, 'sub'=>$Razdel, 'cc'=>$Komponent, 'code'=>$Engname);

function by_code($tabs) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($tabs as $v) {
    $result[$v['code']][] = $v['cc'];
  }
  return $result;
}
```

получаю такой массив

```
Array ( 
  [about] => Array ( 
    [0] => 479 
    [1] => 967 
  ) 
  [doc] => Array ( 
    [0] => 480 
  ) 
  [dop] => Array ( 
    [0] => 481 
  ) 
  [faq] => Array ( 
    [0] => 482 
  ) 
  [off] => Array ( 
    [0] => 483 
  )
)
```

[about], [doc], [dop], [faq], [off] - динамические данные, т.е. может быть и [dsdfg] [124sdr] и т.д.

Как мне это дело вывести, что бы получилось так

```
<div>479 967</div>
<div>480</div>
<div>481</div>
<div>482</div>
<div>483</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $div = '<div>';
    foreach($result[$key] as $v) {
        echo $v . ' ';
    }
    $div .= '</div>';
    echo $div;
}
```

Где `$result` - ваш многомерный массив.

Comment: `echo "<div>".implode(' ', $result[$key])."</div>"` не проще?   и без лишнего пробела в конце

Comment: @teran ну или так

Comment: получается 1 цикл получаем данные, 2 цикл выводим данные?

Comment: function by_code($tabs) {
                        $result = array();
                        foreach ($tabs as $v) {
                            $result[$v['code']][] = $v['cc'];
                        }
                        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                            echo "<div>".implode(' ', $result[$key])."</div>";
                        }
                        return $result;
                      }

Comment: @Sincopa Не совсем получаем и выводим. Многомерный массив просто перебирается двумя циклами.

Comment: А с помощью функции `implode()` и вовсе один раз.

Comment: получается цикл в цикле должен быть верно? Не так как у меня цикл после цикла.